# How to change the process count of the ParallelRunner in Kedro?

Tags: python, kedro

My pipeline makes a lot of HTTP requests. It’s not a CPU-heavy operation, I’d like to spin more processes than the number of CPU cores. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2):

ParallelRunner supports the `max_workers` parameter, but currently there’s no way to pass it from kedro run cli command. It’s done to reduce the complexity of the CLI.
You can add a parameter manually, or just hard-code the value when instantiating the ParallelRunner in `kedro_cli.py`. The runner part might look like:

```
runner_class = load_obj(runner, "kedro.runner") if runner else SequentialRunner
runner_params = {'num_workers': 100} if runner is ParallelRunner else {}

context = load_context(Path.cwd(), env=env)
context.run(
    tags=tag,
    runner=runner_class(**runner_params),
    node_names=node_names,
    from_nodes=from_nodes,
    to_nodes=to_nodes,
    from_inputs=from_inputs,
    load_versions=load_version,
    pipeline_name=pipeline,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

CLI [kedro run](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/development/commands_reference.html#modifying-a-kedro-run)

- [ThreadRunner](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/tutorial/add_another_pipeline.html#optional-kedro-runners)

```
kedro run --runner=ThreadRunner --params=max_workers=6  -pipeline="my_pipeline"
```

- [ParallelRunner](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/nodes_and_pipelines/run_a_pipeline.html#parallelrunner)

```
kedro run --runner=ParallelRunner  --params=max_workers=6 --async --pipeline="my_pipeline"
```